# get data with ajax real time in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create a ajax notification system with laravel and write code that does it.
My question is that at this time every single item in the code goes to the page that I need if a new item was created as a result of the AJAX, a value to be added to the previous value.

my code is

```
$(document).ready(realTime);

function realTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'{{ route( 'getnews' ) }}',
        data:{
            '_token':"{{ csrf_token() }}",
        },
        success: function (result) {


            $.each(result, function (k, v) {

                $('#payam').append($('<option>', {value: k, text: v}, '</option>'));
            });

            setTimeout(realTime, 2000);
        },
        error: function () {
            //handle errors
            alert('error...');
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: If you want real time, you will need to use socket

Comment: I do not know about socket. Can you explain more?

Comment: @ArmanBagheri check out socket.io

Comment: There is no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use laravel broadcasting and jquery or vuejs for crate real time and you can use socket.io when your project is large scale

use laravel doc
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting

and you can use this video course in youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6Rdkv-DLwk